# Node js, how to use draft.js on express framework

Tags: node.js, express, draftjs

I am a noob programmer. I guess can't use `draft.js` on express, but I want to use `draft.js` editor on express. I can't find sample to use `draft.js` on express.

**test.pug**

```
link(rel='stylesheet', type='text/css', href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/draft-js/0.10.1/Draft.css')
script(src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/draft-js/0.10.1/Draft.js')
//and then...?
```

How can I use it?

Comment: You need to be using the React frontend library to make use of Draft.js. Have you read the [docs](https://draftjs.org/docs/overview.html#content)? If so, clarify which bit you're getting stuck on and hopefully people will be able to help.

Comment: maybe You should look for non react wysiwyg editor, cuz I see You are trying to merge pug code with draft package that is made for react

Comment: what about http://summernote.org/

Comment: here are bunch of them that simple and beautiful: https://www.sitepoint.com/10-best-html-wysiwyg-plugins/

Comment: thanks all,
i relize that this problem is beyond my ability after reading yours commnets.
once i will effort this problem

Comment: i added florida wysiwyg Demo editor on my webapp
it it good